# How to find a occurrence of a character in String using java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string and want to sub-string till 3rd occurrence of "," . I can achieve this using Array. here is the code

```
String test ="hi,this,is,a,string.";
String[] testArray = test.split(",");
System.out.println(testArray[0]+","+testArray[1]+","+testArray[2]);
```

Output is :- `hi,this,is`

Is there anyway to achieve the same using "substring(0, text.indexOf(","))" method.Second thing is there could be some instances where there is no "," in the string and i want to handle both scenarios

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I really recommend this, but — yes; there's a [two-arg overload of `indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) that lets you specify the starting position to search at; so you can write:

```
final int firstCommaIndex = test.indexOf(',');
final int secondCommaIndex = test.indexOf(',', firstCommaIndex + 1);
final int thirdCommaIndex = test.indexOf(',', secondCommaIndex + 1);
System.out.println(test.substring(0, thirdCommaIndex));
```

Comment: But it will throw the out of the bound exception if  "," is not in the String

Comment: @user2142786 then you can use try-catch to cover it if you are unsure about occurrence

Comment: @user2142786: Well, it has to do *something* in that case. (Your code, for example, will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there's no comma in the string.) Is there a different behavior that you'd prefer?

Answer (score 0):

So what you are looking for is basically a way to receive the n-th (3rd) index of a char (,) in your String.
While there is no functionality for that in Java's Standard library, you can either create your own construct (which could look like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859949/5604890)),

or alternatively you could use [StringUtils from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), making your desired solution look smth like this:

```
String test ="hi,this,is,a,string.";
int index = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(test, ",", 3);
String desired = test.substring(0, index);
System.out.println(desired);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "hi,this,is,a,string.";

        String regex = "([[^,].]+,?){3}(?=,)";

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher m = re.matcher(test);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Output is :- hi,this,is, . There is an extra "," at the end. is this can be remove with the help of regex or we need to use lastindex of method

Comment: @user2142786 Check my updated code. I edited the regex `([[^,].]+,?){3}(?=,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Other way with stream java 8. This can handle both of your scenarios

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(test.split(",")).limit(3).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```